# router.post / adding nested array to MongoDB database using Node JS, express, mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Below you can find example of location that was created using my Place schema with array of location and tickets. Inside tickets array there's a nested array of notes. I'm trying to use router.post function and get the note uploaded to the database using unshift but without a success. Can you please let me know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

This is the error I'm getting:

*(node:36073) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'tickets' of null
    at Place.findOne.then.place (/Users/fifi/Desktop/FAM./routes/tickets.js:111:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
(node:36073) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:36073) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.*

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5c716edf8f0d6f7b5b4b310f"), 
"location" : [
    {
        "phoneNumber" : "+1 212-226-3126", 
        "website" : "https://www.apple.com", 
        "contactEmail" : "apple1004SoHo@apple.com", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c716edf8f0d6f7b5b4b3110"), 
        "street" : "Prince St", 
        "buildingNumber" : 103, 
        "buildingAddition" : "", 
        "postcode" : "10012", 
        "city" : "New York", 
        "country" : "United States", 
        "latitude" : 40.725056, 
        "longitude" : -73.999027
    }
], 
"tickets" : [
    {
        "status" : "Unassigned", 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c729175bdfe628cb5a205c3"), 
        "ticketUser" : ObjectId("5c6d2e81e6117a2ddb07b070"), 
        "description" : "Test", 
        "priority" : "Medium", 
        "notes" : [

        ], 
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-02-24T12:43:33.342+0000"), 
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-02-24T12:43:33.342+0000")
    }
], 
"customerID" : "Apple", 
"placeID" : "1004", 
"name" : "SoHo", 
"__v" : 2
```

---

```
  router.post('/notes/:id', (req, res) => {
  Place.findOne({
    _id: req.params.id
  })
    .then(place => {
      const newNote = {
        noteBody: req.body.noteBody,
        noteUser: req.user.id,
      }
      place.tickets.notes.unshift(newNote);
      place.save()
        .then(place => {
          res.redirect('back')
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `findOne` returns `null` or `undefined` if the item matching your *query* is not found.
- If the item `place` is `null` then calling `place.tickets` will raise an error

Add an `if` statement to check if your `place` item is `null` before applying the rest of the logic

## Code

```
Place.findOne({
    _id: req.params.id
  })
  .then(place => {
    // Add the IF here
    if (!place) {
      return res.status(404).send('Place not found');
    }

    const newNote = {
      noteBody: req.body.noteBody,
      noteUser: req.user.id,
    }

    place.tickets.notes.unshift(newNote);
    place.save()
      .then(place => {
        res.redirect('back')
      }).catch(err => res.send(err));
  }).catch(err => res.send(err));
```

## Notes

- `.findOne({_id: req.params.id})` is equivalent to `.findById(req.params.id)`
- Don't forget to **`catch`** when you call `then`. Otherwise your request may time out and never return a response if the server encounters an error

Comment: Thanks molamk. I think that this line of code: place.tickets.notes.unshift(newNote); is where my logic fails. I simply have no idea how to access second nested array (notes)...

Comment: No problem. What about that line?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm doing it correctly. I want to grab note (comment) form a form for a specific ticket for specific place. Each ticket has an unique ID. Should I try to findOne by place or findOne by ticket in this case? Again, all 3 all connected and the nesting is a per above (Place > tickets > notes). Sorry if this is confusing, I've been trying to figure it out for few hours now...

Comment: Doing an `unshift` will add your item to `place.tickets.notes` if `notes` is an _array_. I don't have enough details to know if you're doing the right thing there. But I recommend you ask a new question for that specific problem, and if this answers your question on `Cannot read property 'tickets' of null` don't forget to mark this as answered